# Weighted Mean of 3 Measurements: Too Little Information?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I **only** have the following summary data:

- "City A" has an adult population of "n1" : a representative sample of 25% of this adult population was asked for their income, and the average income was "x dollars"
- "City B" has an adult population of "n2" : a representative sample of 25% of this adult population was asked for their income, and the average income was "y dollars"
- "City C" has an adult population of "n3" : a representative sample of 25% of this adult population was asked for their income, and the average income was "z dollars"

Based on **only** this information, I want to estimate the average income of all 3 cities and the standard deviation.

Originally, I had thought that the "Weighted Mean" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) was a good approach for this problem. That is, cities with larger populations should have more of an influence on the final estimate, and cities with smaller populations should have less of an influence on the final estimate. I could then calculate the standard deviation as well.

I started looking at references to perform this calculation (e.g. http://seismo.berkeley.edu/~kirchner/Toolkits/Toolkit_12.pdf), and it appears that individual measurements might be required for this calculation. For example, I would need to have the income of every person interviewed in City A, City B and City C. However, I am only provided with the average income from each of these cities - and furthermore, I am not even provided with the standard deviation of these averages.

**In such a problem, does it still make sense to calculated the Weighted Mean on essentially three measurements? Or in such cases, is it better to refrain from calculating any statistics, seeing that any estimate generated in such a context is likely to be inherently flawed?**

Note: these 3 measurements I am provided with are themselves "means" of other measurements - I am not sure if this further complicates things. E.g. since I am not provided with the variance of each individual mean - will it still be published to calculate the variance of the weighted mean?

Answer (score 2):

Computing the weighted mean or the average using the information from every single citizen is equivalent. Your averages $x$, $y$ and $z$ are defined as
$$
x = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}x_i}{n_1}, \quad y = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_2}y_i}{n_2}, \quad z = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_3}z_i}{n_3},
$$
with $x_i$ being the income of the i'th citizen.
The average income $\mu$ of *all* citizens is computed as
$$
\mu = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}x_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n_2}y_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n_3}z_i}{n_1+n_2+n_3}.
$$
One can reformulate the first equation to
$$
x n_1=\sum_{i=1}^{n_3}x_i
$$
and plug this equation into the average, which leads to the weighted average
$$
\mu = \frac{n_1x+n_2y+n_3z}{n_1+n_2+n_3}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So in short, it doesn't make a difference - correct?

Comment: I guess now I can just use standard formulas to calculate the variance of the weighted average? That is, I don't need the variance of each individual average?